# Executing ExecStopPost on reboot

Tags: systemd

How to configure the service correctly so that the command from ExecStopPost is executed when the OS is rebooted.

`my.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=my.service
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
After=my-service.mount
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/opt/myService/myService.java
 
[Service]
User=UserName
Group=UserGroup
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myService
OOMScoreAdjust=-100
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java ./myService.java start
TimeoutStartSec=90
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/java ./myService.java stop
TimeoutStopSec=30
 
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```